# How to make a button which submits a form but doesn't reload the page?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have a form, which takes all the inputs settings form an array. Submin button is constructed ths way:

```
<input name="save" class="button" type="submit" value="Save Settings" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" />
```

And function, whch handles saving or deeting operation is contructd this way:

```
function theme_settings_page() {
    global $themename,$theme_options;
    $i=0;
    $message='';
        if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
            foreach ($theme_options as $value) {
                update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ); }
            foreach ($theme_options as $value) {
        if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) { update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  ); } else { delete_option( $value['id'] ); } }
                $message='saved';}
        else if( 'reset' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
            foreach ($theme_options as $value) {
                delete_option( $value['id'] ); }
                $message='reset';}
        if ( $message=='saved' && $i==0 )  echo '<div id="message" class="apply"><strong>Ustawienia zachowane.</strong></div>' ;
        if ( $message=='reset' ) echo '<div id="message" class="reset"><strong>Ustawienia zresetowane.</strong></div>';
```

The $value['id'] is actually a value taken from array descibing all the inputs. The form begins and ends with nothing more than:

```
<form method="post"></form>
```

The content of the form is made as tabs. So the question is: how to make the page not reload when Save button is being hit??

PS: I'm not sure I gave you enough data, but if you need to know something more, just ask. I was looking through the web for an examples but I couldn't find anythig appropriate.

Comment: Research [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wp_ajax_+is%3Aa) and [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wp_ajax_+is%3Aa). All your `save` and `reset` code should go inside an Ajax callback (`wp_ajax_*`).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the jQuery ajax function.
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I would do that, but in every example I found there is an 'url:  ”whateverfile.php”,' mark, and I don't have a separate php file to store all the form data. How I'm suppoded to to that wthout having php file, or maybe I should use the php file where the form is included?

Comment: Just set the url so that it will point to the file in which your funcion is written, even if it is the same file as your form.

Answer (score 0):

Just return false on Click and use AJAX to submit form (see jQuery for easy AJAX):

```
<input name="save" class="button" type="submit" value="Save Settings" onclick="doSomething(); return false;"/>
```

```
$.ajax({url: "xyz.com/do.php", type: "POST", data: {a: $("save").val()}})
```